# Why the menu of ActionBar didn't change the background

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I try to custom the `ActionBar`.

In the `Fragment` , I use the following code to set `ActionBar`.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
```

The `actionbar.xml` is like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bar_background" >

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bar_icon"/>    

</RelativeLayout >
```

But it show like the following picture:

[image]

Why the `menu button` didn't change the Background? Did I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

`CustomView` is for putting your custom views (e.g. created classes) - `Buttons`, styled `TextViews`, other widgets etc. You are looking just for background, so you might use:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bar_background));
```

or (better, prefered) style your `ActionBar` with styles:

```
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bar_background</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

with new `AppCompat` you might use custom, easily colored `Toolbar` ([doc here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html))

Comment: If I use `style` , how to set the position of `ICON` ?

Comment: you can't, this is `ActionBar` - it has to be consistent with guidelines. you might try above mentioned `Toolbar` or you have to create `Custom View` like you already do, but with transparent background and the real background drawable set using above snippets